# Is a ValueList() a string?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

I am trying to convert the results of a query into an array

```
this.arLibrary  = ValueList(qryLibrary.ID).ListToArray();
```

And I get the following error

> Detail A script statement must end with ";".
>
> The CFML compiler was
>   processing:
>
> - A script statement beginning with
>     this.arLibrary on line 43, column 9.
>
>   A cfscript tag
>     beginning on line 21, column 2.
>
> KnownColumn -1   KnownLine -1
>   KnownText <unknown>   Line 43   Message Invalid construct.
>   Snippet this.arLibrary =
>   ValueList(qryLibrary.ID).
>   StackTrace

This does work

```
temp    = ValueList(qryLibrary.ID);
this.arMetricLibActive  = temp.ListToArray();
```

It makes me wonder if `ValueList()` is a string

Comment: File this to https://bugbase.adobe.com/ under Language?  However, I have a feeling it'll fall under "Won't Fix".

Comment: Given that array functions work on query columns, you might be looking to do something unnecessary.

Comment: *Is a ValueList() a string?*  `writeDump(temp.getClass().name)`;

Comment: @dan baruk, not in Lucee they don't.  That is an undocumented behavior only present in Adobe CF.  Lucee has a dedicated function to retrieve a query's column data as an array.

Comment: @Leigh: It returns: `java.lang.String`. On a similar note `ValueList(qryLibrary.ID).getClass();` crashes

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Yep. You can typically use that technique to find out the return type of a function.  Not that surprising I guess. While not exactly the same as the contains() issue, it sounds like a similar limitation (or bug).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a string.  The error is a parsing issue in the CFML engine.  The same syntax works fine in Lucee.  File a bug like Henry suggested.

Here's an example in the CommandBox REPL

```
CFSCRIPT-REPL: foo = queryNew('bar')
{
    "COLUMNS":[
        "BAR"
    ],
    "DATA":[

    ]
}
CFSCRIPT-REPL: valueList( foo.bar ).listToArray()
[

]
```

Answer (score 2):

James, it'd be useful if you read error messages when they are presented to you: they generally contain pertinent information. I don't mean this in a "stating the obvious" sort of way, but rather that it's actually a very important part of troubleshooting problems. You are faced with an error message from the *compiler*, which means the error occurred when the source code was being compiled. However you are asking a question about data types, which - in a loosely and dynamically typed language like CFML - is a runtime consideration. "Runtime" implies "when the code is being run" which is intrinsically after the code is compiled. If the code can't compile: it won't be run.

So the issue is not whether `valueList()` returns a string or anything like that.

The issue here is that there is a bug in ColdFusion's CFML parser, and it is not able to interpret this expression:

```
ValueList(qryLibrary.ID).ListToArray()
```

I don't know *why* there's a problem with this: there should be no problem with parsing the calling of a method on another function call's return value; and indeed it seems to be a peculiarity of using `valueList()` like this, as opposed to built-in functions in general.

File a bug.

As for what to do about it in your code in the meantime, I think Dan is right: generally one can use a query column as an array anyhow, provided one uses bracket notation to reference the column, eg: `qryLibrary["ID"]`. Brad draws attention to this not working on Lucee, but... this is neither here nor there, and just something that Lucee needs to deal with. There was a bug raised for this in Railo - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-641 - but they declined to address it, with only semi-valid reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

**Epilog:**

This works on ColdFusion 2016 and above

```
<cfscript>
qryLibrary = QueryNew("ID", "varchar");

qryLibrary.addrow({"id" : "cat"});
qryLibrary.addrow({"id" : "dog"});
qryLibrary.addrow({"id" : "fish"});

writedump(qryLibrary);

arLibrary  = ValueList(qryLibrary.ID).ListToArray();

writedump(arLibrary);
</cfscript>
```

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=6588296c-5e4d-49a4-894b-4986513e9e30/0ecde857-6d28-4e43-88a7-7830c109ab11/84cd7e81-16f8-43d7-b4c9-5490b1b5d007.cfm

Comment: Note, that like most list functions it eliminates null values. If for some reason you want to preserve those, use `ListToArray(",", true)`.